# selecting principal component for wealth index?

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, pca, stata

While creating a wealth index using the household asset (dichotomized
), Can we take the second principal component (comp 2) if it has more relative positive eigenvectors (For example: as shown in the attached picture)? If yes, which is the best reference to quote. Thank you [image]

Comment: If PCA is being used to create a single summary, the principle is that the first PC captures the largest possible fraction of total variability, which makes it the best possible summary. There is a lot of small print and much room for discussion about the merits of this approach, but that is standard.

Answer (score 0):

The sign of an eigenvector is arbitrary, so you cannot take it into consideration when choosing principal components.

Comment: _should not_ rather than _cannot_

Comment: @NickCox, thank you very much for the answer. It is great to help. In some point, I get practical confusion. In above-attached file, If we see in PC1 variables such as motorbike, refrigerator, vehicle, etc. have a negative magnitude. So, in the case of counting wealth, it will lead to the opposite direction (i.e those who have a vehicle, refrigerator, motorbike etc. will contribute to poor wealth). Therefore from the practical point of view, I thought PC2 will be good. :)